# AdMob in libGDX game on iOS

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, admob, mobivm

My question might seem quite easy for you, but I have no experience at this point.

I want to implement AdMob in libGDX game on iOS devices(it's already implemented in Android version). Unlucky examples on Admob website targets Swift and Objective-C.

I've found something like [RoboVM iOS Bindings](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings), but last commit was on 16 Feb 2015.

So i need to ask - is this still good and acceptable way to implement AdMob in libGDX iOS projects?

I've found some questions that involves both - libGDX and AdMob, but from 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods/tree/master/google-mobile-ads/ios), last commit 10 months ago.

[robovm-robopods](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods) repository under MobiVM hood.

You can use `2.2.2` version of robovm-robopods

Inject in this way :

```
implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:2.2.2"
```

If you like to use SNAPSHOT version, use SNAPSHOT version

```
implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:2.2.3-SNAPSHOT"
```

---

If you're using older version of android gradle plugin replace `implementation` with `compile`

Comment: Yes, looks much better than RoboVM iOS Bindings. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't think so, You've click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in by green colour, check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/350059)

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed. I'm pretty sure that I've clicked the check mark. Sorry.